# How can I solve this elusive error in my multi-GPU Pytorch setup?

Tags: gpu, ubuntu-16.04, pytorch, multi-gpu

I have spent the past day trying to figure out how to use multiple GPUs. In theory, parallelizing models across multiple GPUs is supposed to be as as easy as simply wrapping models with `nn.DataParallel`. However, I have found that this does not work for me. To use the most simple and canonical thing I could find for proof of this, I ran the code in the [Data Parallelism tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/data_parallel_tutorial.html), line for line.

I have tried everything from only having a specific permutation of my GPUs be visible to CUDA to reinstalling everything related to CUDA but can't figure out why I cannot run with multiple GPUs. Some information about my machine:
Operating System: Ubuntu 16.04
GPUS: 4 1080tis
Pytorch version: 1.01
CUDA version: 10.0

The error code is the following:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyboardInterrupt                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-0f0d83e9ef13> in <module>
      1 for data in rand_loader:
      2     input = data.to(device)
----> 3     output = model(input)
      4     print("Outside: input size", input.size(),
      5           "output_size", output.size())

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in __call__(self, *input, **kwargs)
    487             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    488         else:
--> 489             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    490         for hook in self._forward_hooks.values():
    491             hook_result = hook(self, input, result)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/parallel/data_parallel.py in forward(self, *inputs, **kwargs)
    141             return self.module(*inputs[0], **kwargs[0])
    142         replicas = self.replicate(self.module, self.device_ids[:len(inputs)])
--> 143         outputs = self.parallel_apply(replicas, inputs, kwargs)
    144         return self.gather(outputs, self.output_device)
    145 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/parallel/data_parallel.py in parallel_apply(self, replicas, inputs, kwargs)
    151 
    152     def parallel_apply(self, replicas, inputs, kwargs):
--> 153         return parallel_apply(replicas, inputs, kwargs, self.device_ids[:len(replicas)])
    154 
    155     def gather(self, outputs, output_device):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/parallel/parallel_apply.py in parallel_apply(modules, inputs, kwargs_tup, devices)
     73             thread.start()
     74         for thread in threads:
---> 75             thread.join()
     76     else:
     77         _worker(0, modules[0], inputs[0], kwargs_tup[0], devices[0])

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/threading.py in join(self, timeout)
   1054 
   1055         if timeout is None:
-> 1056             self._wait_for_tstate_lock()
   1057         else:
   1058             # the behavior of a negative timeout isn't documented, but

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/threading.py in _wait_for_tstate_lock(self, block, timeout)
   1070         if lock is None:  # already determined that the C code is done
   1071             assert self._is_stopped
-> 1072         elif lock.acquire(block, timeout):
   1073             lock.release()
   1074             self._stop()

KeyboardInterrupt:
```

Any insight into this error would be very much appreciated. From my relatively limited systems and CUDA knowledge, it has to do with some sort of locking, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to fix this.

Comment: The traceback is from keyboard interrupt. Do you have the traceback from the actual error? Or it just hangs?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that it hangs.

Comment: @JeffreyWang have you solved this yet? I'm currently stuck with the same problem and my system just freezes as well.